# AWK: Need to swap values between two columns if the left one is smaller than the right one

Tags: awk, sed, swap, tabular

So what I've got so far is a Bed-Table file and the problem with this file is, that in some rows the value in column 2 is bigger than the value in column 3.

Is there any one liner in awk, which would swap these two values, so that the table always got the smaller value in col 2 and the bigger one in col 3?

```
chr01    100    200
chr02    300    150
```

so in this example the desired output would be:

```
chr01    100    200
chr02    150    300
```

Comment: What the heck is a `Bed-Table file`? Even google doesn't seem to now.

Comment: A bed file is a table, which contains coordinates of DNA sequences within a genome. You can use it to extract sequences from a genome or do analysis like are there genes, which are close to each other or sequences overlapping each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just swap the columns if they're in the wrong order, using a temporary variable:

```
$ awk '$2 > $3 { temp = $3; $3 = $2; $2 = temp } 1' OFS='\t' file
```

`1` at the end is a common shorthand for `{print}`, so each line is printed. Setting the output field separator `OFS` to a tab character preserves the format.

Alternatively:

```
$ awk -F'\t' '$2 > $3 { $0 = $1 FS $3 FS $2 } 1' file
```

Rearrange the contents of the line if necessary, using the input field separator `FS` which has been set to a tab character.

Answer (score 0):

You could use awk,

```
awk '$2>$3{x=$3;$3=$2;$2=x}1' file
```

Comment: The command switches the desired values but it causes an error because it somehow deletes the tab between the columns

Comment: `awk '$2>$3{x=$3;$3=$2;$2=x}1' file | sed 's/ \+/\t/g'`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{ printf("%s %d %d\n",$1,($2 < $3) ? $2 : $3,($2 < $3) ? $3 : $2) }' file
```